# Trying to remove 'val' from a linked list but keep getting segmentation fault when I try to cout to check results

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void remove (const T &val) {
    node* placer  = head->next;
    node* prev_placer = head;
    while (placer) {
        if (placer->data == val) {
            prev_placer->next = placer->next;
            free(placer);           
        }
        prev_placer = placer;
        placer = placer->next;
    }
    if (head->data == val) {
        this->head = head->next;
        head->prev = nullptr;
    }
    if (tail->data = val) {
        this->tail = tail->prev;
        tail->next = nullptr;
    }
}
```

An eexample: If my list was [h, e, l, l, o], and I wanted to `remove('l')`, then my list == [h, e, o]. However, whenever I try to print my work to test it, I keep getting segmentation faults.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. This looks like C++, not JS.

Comment: After you `free(placer)` you continue to use `placer`. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: In C++ you should be using `new` and `delete`, not `malloc()` and `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your main loop, you are using `placer` after it's been deleted. Also, you should not be using `free` in C++, use `delete` instead (provided that you have used `new` to create a node; or do you use `malloc` there? Then are you maybe trying to write c code? But then I think the `nullptr` keyword is C++-specific...).

A corrected version of the loop might look something like this:

```
while (placer) {
    if (placer->data == val) {
        prev_placer->next = placer->next;
        delete placer;
        placer = prev_placer->next;
    }
    else
    {
        prev_placer = placer;
        placer = placer->next;
    }
}
```

A general recommendation to avoid the unhealthy mixture between C and C++ (they **are** different) would be to [pick up a good book on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).